# Commented Out and Even Deleted Code Being Called in the Application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, debugging, webforms

This is one the most weirdest issues I have ever seen. I have a js file with many JavaScript methods.

I commented out few lines of code but for some reason when I debug it goes over these commented out lines and executes them. I've even deleted them but they still execute.

I deleted the browser cache, restarted my machine done everything and still same problems.

It is a VS 2008 ASP.NET Webforms application.

Comment: Have you tried CTRL+F5, repeated refreshing, and doing a full rebuild of your project (like "Clean..." in Eclipse)?

Comment: Try using private browsing mode or another machine. This is almost certainly a caching issue.

Comment: Or maybe you have two workspaces with two copies of the project... you're editing one and testing the other. Sounds stupid, but I've seen a colleague spend half an hour debugging this :)

Comment: Not sure what browser you are using, but have you tried a different browser? Preferably, one that you never ran the old code with.  If the commented out lines behave as expected in the new browser, then at least you have narrowed down the problem to the old browser.

Comment: The app only renders properly on IE. Thanks to the off shore team :)

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the solutions worked. I found another thing that when debugging JS using VS 2010. It skips lines when debugging. Even the yellow debugging arrow is placed incorrectly on empty lines.

Comment: Just noticed that in private browsing the JavaScript file is refreshed properly and the code works. Now the question is how to make 100% that in public browsing the cache is deleted.